# AngularJS and RouteProvider how to update a small section in the page

Tags: angularjs

I have a conceptual question, I have a site with 4 sections in one row

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| header                                                                                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            |                               |                                     |      |
| 1          | 2                             | 3                                   | 4    |
| Side Menu  | <div ui-view='ui_side_view'>  | <div ui-view='ui_container_view'>   |      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Section #2 has the `<ng-view>` tag, so I can't use it anywhere else ( right? )
Now I'm trying to have a concept like this:

- URL of /charter - when no params exists - load history in section #2
- URL of /charter?id=1 - when "id" exists - load the history in section #2 AND content of a template in section #3

Router is like:

```
.when('/charter', { controller: 'CharterCtrl', template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl">Loading...</div>' })
```

## Issue 1:

When the URL changes to `/charter?id=2` - nothing happens ( I'm using html5mode )
That's my main problem, other than that, I have a dynamic templating code to solve issue #2 below ...

## Issue 2:

Also curious about this, If I'll change the routeProvider to be something like:

```
.when('/charter', { controller: 'CharterCtrl', template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl">Loading...</div>' })
.when('/charter/:id', { controller: 'CharterContainerCtrl', template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl">Loading...</div>', })
```

How can I combine in the URL more than one parameter like:

```
/charter?id=4&cache=true
```

If now the URL formatting is

```
/charter/<id>/ ... < where the "cache" goes ?
```

## Update with $stateParam

My HTML is now:

- section #2 have: `<div ui-view="ui_side_view"></div>`
- section #3
  have: `<div ui-view="ui_container_view"></div>`

They seem to work for the first time only, as the "templateUrl" from the $stateProvider does drop the content in the right place ...
But any other URL change - nothing happens

So my router is now:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "/index.pcgi",
        views: {
            "ui_side_view": { templateUrl: "templates/empty.html" },
            "ui_container_view": { template: "index.side.empty" }
        }
    })
    .state('charter', {
        url: "/charter.pcgi",
        views: {
            "ui_side_view": { template: "charter.ui_side_view <a href='/charter.pcgi/q/test'>click</a>", controller: "CharterCtrl" },
            "ui_container_view": { template: "charter.ui_container_view", controller: "CharterContainerCtrl" }
        }
    })    
    .state('charter.q', {     
        url: "/charter.pcgi/q/:q",        
        views: {
            "ui_side_view": { template: "charter.q.ui_side_view", controller: "CharterCtrl" },
            "ui_container_view": { template: "charter.q.ui_container_view", controller: "CharterContainerCtrl" }
        }
    });
```

In my controller.js I"m trying to debug:

```
.controller('CharterContainerCtrl', ['$scope', '$state','$stateParams', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {

    console.debug($state.params);
    console.debug($stateParams);

}]);
```

Both are empty

When changing URL from:

- `/charter.pci` to `/charter.pcgi/q/test1` - templates are being loaded and also the controller is loaded and I see `console.debug()` msgs.
- `/charter.pcgi/q/test1` to `/charter.pcgi/q/test2/` nothing happens, and the controller is not loaded again as I don't see `console.debug()` msgs.
- Going back from `/charter.pcgi/q/test2/` to `/index.pcgi` - works.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QhabHDvi29Texwy8G441

- You can play with going back and forth between charter.pcgi and index.pcgi buttons
- But if you click inside the charter.pcgi buttons to initiate /charter.pcgi/q/someid - it doesn't do anything

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not an answer, but an advice that you may like : consider using ui-router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router You can play around with nested view in this routing system :)

Comment: ui-router seems to fit more than what I'm using right now ( w/o all my major tweaks in Angular to achieve what I need arrrr ), but I have the same problem - I can't seem to change section #3, I tried with $location.url and $state.go ... the URL changes - but nothing happens ... :( using form of /charter/q/:id

Comment: Not only the URL is not changing ... the $state.params / $stateParams is empty :/

Comment: Could you update your question with what your tried in ui-router ? Give your states definition and the code from where you are trying to call the $stateParams

Comment: You're saying that it works in the first place. Could you show how you use $state.go to change state ? If that's the point i'll give you an answer with the right syntax

Comment: I've disabled it in the controller, for the example - see under state "charter" -> views -> ui_side_view -> <a href='/charter.pcgi/q/test'>click</a>", but just in case my syntax is wrong ( their docs are not so much clarify ) - I tried both  $state.go('charter.q', {q: 'test'}); and  $state.go('charter', {q: 'test'}); and  $state.go('charter.q'); ... don't know ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79751/discussion-between-okazari-and-ricky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke a state change with ui-router you should actually use the ui-router build-in directive `ui-sref` instead of `href`

In html here is some example of transition to your states

```
<button ui-sref="charter"></button>
<button ui-sref="charter.q({ q: myparamvalue})"></button>
```

Here is how you will do it in JS if you need

```
$state.go('charter');
$state.go('charter.q',{ q: myparamvalue});
```

Hope it solve your problem, let me know if you're still running on an issue.

**EDIT :**

After a long conversation on what Ricky exactly wanted we found what was the problem.

Actualy he didn't know the proper use of nester states in ui-router

We finaly made this : (working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OesgfCdjdzObWtX4d7FC?p=preview) just add a space somewhere if it don't work).

here are the states

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: "",
      views: {
            "ui_side_view": { templateUrl: "empty.html" },
            "ui_container_view": { template: "index.side.empty <button ui-sref='charterq({ q: 1})')>q=1</button>" }
        }
    }) 
    .state('charter', {
        url:"/charter.pcgi",
        views: {
            "ui_side_view": { templateUrl: "charter.side.html", controller: "CharterCtrl" },
            "ui_container_view": { templateUrl: "charter.container.html", controller: "CharterContainerCtrl" },
        }  
    })    
    .state('charterq', {     
        url: "/charter.pcgi/q/{q}",         
        views: {
            "ui_side_view": { templateUrl: "charter.side.html", controller: "CharterCtrl" },
            "ui_container_view": { templateUrl: "charter.container.html", controller: "CharterContainerCtrl" },
        }
    });
```

In the HTML there is two nester ui-view named "ui_side_view" and "ui_container_view"

In addition to this answer i'd think that the `charterq` state "may" be a substate of `charter`. But he would need to modify the index.html template in consequences.

Also keep it mind if that you load a ressource out of this "q" parameter you'd prefer to use a resolve on you ui_container_view as @mhadadi said on the other answer :

```
"ui_container_view": { template: "charter.q.ui_container_view", controller: "CharterContainerCtrl" ,
                            resolve:{
                                        q:function($http){
                                             return //your http call
                                           },              
                                     }
                                 }
                }
```

You will be able to get this like this in the associated controller :

```
.controller('CharterContainerCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, q) {
    console.debug(q); //This q will be the "data" return by your $http call in the resolve.
    console.debug($state.params);
    console.debug($stateParams);

}]);
```

Glad we finally made it :)

Comment: I also tried that - the URL change - but the "template" value doesn't change

Comment: I think it also got something to do with the fact that the $stateProvider loads my charter templates ( basically the entire route ) even when the site is currently loaded on the "index.pcgi" page, instead of being loaded just when I click on "charter" menu item ..., actually looking it again - the "index" state never loaded .. I don't see the "index." template when loading the site without any path

Comment: I got it, my router for the "index" state wasn't correct, leaving url: "" empty is not something I can do at the moment I have to specify my second example for index.pcgi ( blank url will load the actual site ) - anyway, I'll edit my question with the correct routing and now switching from charter.pcgi to index.pcgi - works

Comment: @Ricky I edited the answer according to our discussion

Comment: Got it , and yes :) thank you very much for you time spent on this !

Answer (score 0):

I think resolve in ui-routing maybe help you 
something like this

```
.state('project', {
              url: "/:proId",
              templateUrl:function($stateParams){return "/project/main/view?pro="+$stateParams.proId },
              resolve:{
                 proId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams,proId){
                        return $stateParams.proId;
                    }],             
                }})
```

---

with your charter values

```
.state('charter.q', {     
        url: "/charter.pcgi/q/:q",        
        views: {
            "ui_side_view": { template: "charter.q.ui_side_view", controller: "CharterCtrl" },
            "ui_container_view": { template: "charter.q.ui_container_view", controller: "CharterContainerCtrl" ,
                            resolve:{
                                        q: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams,q){
                                             return $stateParams.q;
                                           }],              
                                     }
                                 }
                }
```

Comment: Can you edit your example with my 'charter' values ? I'm not sure which variables I'm suppose to replace with my vars

Comment: oh I got it ... I've added it, it still have the same behavior - like the controller is not reloaded with the new param ... basically nothing happens from /charter.pcgi - to /charter.pcgi/q/test1